# ¿Porque mis correos no son aceptados utilizado nodeMAiler y MailGun y me da un error mensaje 5.7.1 This mail is rejected as it is not RFC compliant?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, email, nodemailer

Hola comunidad SO espero me puedan ayudar con mi problema, verán estoy creando un servidor de correos sencillos, utilizando nodemailer y mailgun, el cual tiene el siguiente código:

```
const { Router } = require('express');
const nodeMailer = require('nodemailer')

// settins
const router = Router();

router.post('/send-email', async (req, res) => {

    const { name, email, phone, message } = req.body

    const contentHTML = `<h1 style="color:red;" > 
                    Hello there, you have a new message/h1>
                    <p>Email:${email}</p>
                    <p>name:${name}</p> 
                    <p>Phone:${phone}</p>
                    <p>MEssages:${message}</p>`


    const transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.mailgun.org',
        port: 587,
        secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            user: process.env.MAIL, // generated ethereal user
            pass: process.env.PASS, // generated ethereal password
        },
    })

    try {
        const info = await transporter.sendMail({
            from: 'Portfolio website',
            to: process.env.EMAIL_TARGET,
            subject: 'Some One needs to talk',
            text: contentHTML
        })
        console.log('success',info);
        return res.send(`succes: ${info.messageId}`)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('there was an error', error);
        return res.send(`sorry there was an error ${error}`)
    }
})


module.exports = router;
```

Aparentemente los mensajes si se envía con excito pero son rechazados, al revisar el log encontre esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con el mensaje

> 5.7.1 This mail is rejected as it is not RFC compliant

Entonces no se como arreglar esto, para este servicio estoy utilizando el sandbox por defecto que da mailgun, no he agregado aun un dominio propio, lo estoy enviando a un dominio privado que yo tengo con ZOHO mail. pero este no recibe los mensajes y realmente no se como arreglar el problema, actualmente todo lo estoy haciendo desde localhost. y simplemente estoy utilizando nodemailer. Cualquier ayuda va ser bien venida

Comment: Hola, Gerardo. ¿Tienes definido correctamente el from (quién envía el correo)?

Comment: No amigo, solo puse un mobre ramdon. Debe coincidir con el usuario que uso para loggin o el de mi formulario de contacto?

Comment: Debe ser un correo [válido](https://nodemailer.com/message/)

Comment: Tienen toda la razón, Ahora si ya pude enviarlo, aparece como recibido, pero no lo veo en mi bandeja de entrada ni en spam tampoco :/

Comment: @GerardoGuevara recuerda que el envío de emails no es un proceso síncrono. Son colas de mensajes. Lo otro: no olvides usar un mismo dominio (`@dominio.com`) para el from y el reply-to.

Comment: Debería entrar en bandeja de entrada o carpeta de spam. Dependiendo de la configuración que tengas, si el dominio tiene establecido registro SPF, etc.

Comment: Gracias tienes razon olvidaba eso @Alfabravo solo que en mailgun ya aparece como entregado, pero en zoho no me aparece aun, esto es normal?.

Comment: Entregado = el servidor SMTP le mandó el mensaje al servidor de correo destino, que dijo ACK, recibido. Nada más. El servidor de correo destino, después, va actualizando los buzones individuales con los nuevos mensajes. Es realmente asíncrono. Caso extremo de gmail, que tiene diferentes buzones en diferentes servidores, sincronizados y blablabla. No Es Inmediato! :)

Comment: gracias @Alfabravo esperare un poco entonces

Comment: @Alfabravo todo funcionando, gracias brother, si puedes responde para darte la mejor respuesta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error:

```
5.7.1 This mail is rejected as it is not RFC compliant
```

Suele arrojar porque no tienes establecido un remitente correcto o válido en el campo from. Cambia este campo en la configuración por un correo válido y lo más probable es que te envíe correctamente.

Otros posibles casos podrían ser qué:

- La IP esté en una blacklist. Suele suceder por ejemplo cuando se envían correos spam y se añaden en listas donde se comprueba a nivel mundial si posee buena o mala reputación.
- Si la IP o el dominio fue bloqueada por el destinatario.

Tienes mayor información en el siguiente enlace:  [SMTP Code: "554 5.7.1" and the message is rejected](https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article?legacyId=TECH169847&SAMLRequest=%5BB%408d0355a)